# what is good solution call from frontend to backend in HTML5 with java spring

Tags: spring

I am bit confused with my project How to call back end from front end,

There are two solution avaliable.

Frontned is HTML5/jQuery and backed with rest service in spring:

1. Passing JSESSIONID on url
2. Passing user name and password on header -md5 security

Comment: Holy crap dont do any of those. Particular #2. Unless you have cookies disabled it should just work,

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything preventing you from passing JSESSIONID as a cookie as is the "normal" way to do it?

Comment: Hi Pap,i thought md5 is more secure than JSESSIONID. By the way where i can find a sample /example on JSESSIONID .

Comment: If you are concerned about man-in-the-middle type attacks, then do all communication over SSL. Not sure what you're after when you say "sample on JSESSIONID". It's the standard method to handle sessions in a Java web application and it's implemented by default in all Java web containers (Tomcat, Jetty, Jboss, etc etc etc)

Comment: instead of using JESESSION id, why dont use oauth2 which is latest trend , one more question.  will it performance issue ??Example.http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org.

Comment: If your REST services are stateless and all you want to achieve is authentication then oath2 is another way to go. It's a bit more to implement and you need to set up an oauth2 provider, but that's all fairly standard. Typically though, you would combine oauth2 with sessions to avoid having to re-validate the oauth2 hash on every request. But it all depends on what you are trying to achieve, what your constraints are and what, if any, architectural limitations you have. For some reason you don't seem to want to use sessions, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: you are right.>>> you would combine oauth2 with sessions to avoid having to re-validate the oauth2 hash on every request.i dont want to go with MVC pattern which is impletemd with spring default. just call the restservice with own html client(ajax call) but could nt find a proper sample or doc with using jessionId for html client

Comment: If you are using the standard AJAX method (XmlHttpRequest or equivalent), the browser will automatically add the JSESSIONID cookie, just as it would on a "normal" request. It feels like you are trying to solve problems that doesn't exist, or create problems that aren't necessary. Don't reinvent the wheel, build your solution according to standard patterns. If you are using AJAX, then use Spring MVC on the server. Add spring-security for the oath2 pieces, if you need that.